# When do car manufacturers stop making the current model year and start the next model year?

Tags: honda, manufacturer

This question might not belong here but I don't know where else to ask a general car question.  I will delete/close if the mods think this question is crap.

Does anyone know when the last batch of the current model year's cars usually come out?  I'm just curious about this.  I used logic when thinking about this but I could totally be wrong.

Let's use 2010 and 2011 as our example years.  My family bought a 2011 Civic in Nov 2010.  I think when they went in Oct 2010 to look at cars, there were some 2011 models for people to look at, just not to purchase, or at least we didn't purchase in Oct for some reason.  Going by this, I'm estimating the manufacturer must have started building the cars in July 2010 or so, finish by end of Aug or early Sept, and then transport the cars to be in showrooms by Oct.

If they start building the 2011 models in July 2010, I would assume they would have stopped building the 2010 models in June 2010 since it will take some time for them to reset all the "robots" on the assembly line for the next model, assuming the next model is different compared to the previous model.

That would mean the last batch of 2010 cars would be shipped to dealerships in July.  Is my logic/guess correct or does someone know the true workflow of the car manufacturers and can enlighten me?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. Each manufacturer will work off a different schedule

Comment: @Zaid, If I specifically said Hondas, could we leave this question open?

Comment: Even if you did, I'd expect that any answer you get will be subject to regional variations and business policy changes (too localalized?) It might fly, but I struggle to see how this would relate to motor vehicle maintenance and repair. Leave it open for now and let the community decide.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about all manufacturers but I do specifically know for Volkswagen who'se model year starts in October.  I have a 2003 registered VW Bora, registered on 17th Dec 2003.  However, it build year on the sticker in the boot (trunk) tells me it is a 2004 model.

Answer (score 1):

My family has been in the automotive business for several generations, and if you look at the title verses the ID plate you will find that, at least for American made, the rule of thumb is, 8th month same year model, 9th month next year model.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why people answer when they have no clue.  The last car built for the current model
year will roll off the assembly line, no later than August 31 of that year.  All manufacturers end the current year model in July or August of that same year.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you have any references to back up this assertion? 'All' is a very broad term...